# android studio:MotionLayout Transition doesn't start programmatically in screen

Tags: java, android-studio, android-motionlayout

I have a map of the northest europe and what I want to do is to start programmaticaly a specific transition. I have created in total 6 transitions because i have 7 countries. So for example, trans1: Lithuania -> Latvia , trans2: Latvia -> Estonia, trans3: Estonia -> Finland etc. So techically, without the need of the user touching or swipe in screen or even put any button to start this animation I want to just start a specific transition, let's say the transistion trans3.

I have created succesfully the transitions and the constraint sets and

this is the layout file where the imageView "main" its going to be animated: (the imageView3 is the map)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/motion_layout"

    app:motionDebug="SHOW_ALL"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_map2_scene"
    tools:context=".Map2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dok2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.818"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.469"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/maincircle" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_play2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PLAY"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_buttom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.903" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

and this is the source file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/trans1"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/latvia"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/lithuania"
        motion:pathMotionArc="startHorizontal"
        
        motion:duration="3000">
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/trans2"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/latvia"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/estonia"
        
        motion:pathMotionArc="startHorizontal"
        motion:duration="3657" >
        <KeyFrameSet >
            <KeyPosition
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/main"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
                motion:percentX="5"
                motion:pathMotionArc="startVertical" />
            <KeyAttribute
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/main"
                motion:framePosition="27"
                android:translationZ="6dp" />

        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/trans3"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/estonia"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/finland"
        
        motion:duration="2729">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyPosition
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/main"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
                motion:percentX="-5" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/trans4"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/finland"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/sweden"
        
        motion:pathMotionArc="startVertical"
        motion:duration="2652" >
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyPosition
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/main"
                motion:framePosition="90"
                motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
                motion:pathMotionArc="startHorizontal"
                motion:percentY="-0.6"
                motion:percentX="0.7" />

        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/trans5"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/sweden"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/denmark"
        
        motion:duration="2265" >
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyPosition
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/main"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
                motion:percentX="-0.1"
                motion:percentY="0.75" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/trans6"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/denmark"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/norway"
        
        motion:duration="3000" >
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyPosition
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/main"
                motion:framePosition="50"
                motion:keyPositionType="deltaRelative"
                motion:percentX="1.25"
                motion:percentY="0.5" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/lithuania">
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.746"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.898"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/latvia">
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.659"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.833"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="22dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />

    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/estonia"
         >
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.557"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.838"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="21dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/finland" >
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.492"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.842"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/sweden" >
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.559"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.559"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/denmark" >
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.746"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.325"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/norway" >
        <Constraint
            motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.556"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.267"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/main" />
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

and this is the scene i want the transition to start

```
package com.example.discovereurope2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Map2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button play_button;
    private Region region;
    private MotionLayout motionLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map2);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        play_button = findViewById(R.id.bt_play2);
        String n = getIntent().getStringExtra("country");
        region = (Region) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("RegionClass");


        motionLayout = findViewById(R.id.motion_layout) ;
        motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.trans3);
        motionLayout.animate();


        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Map2.this, Questions.class);
                String cCountry = String.valueOf(region.getCurrentCountryID());
                intent.putExtra("countryID",cCountry);
                intent.putExtra("RegionClass", region);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

as you can see I got the motionLayout and I call the function to start the specific transition I want but nothing happens. How can Istart a specific transition? Like for example trans3? This is what I want, I don't need onClick or onSwipe or something like that neither autoTransition. I tried to find anything everywhere but almost everyone use onClick or onSwipe.

Answer (score 0):

You are before the attachToWindow so there are a limited number of commands that work.

```
motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.trans3);
motionLayout.setProgress(0)
```

You might need specific transitions with the attribute `motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd"`

The typical use case is a fixed on start up transition.

`.animate()` is a method on view for getting "ViewPropertyAnimator" it has no relation to MotionLayout.